# $M \bigotimes_R (\Pi_{i\in I} B_i) \ncong \Pi_{i \in I} (M \bigotimes B_i)$

Tags: commutative-algebra

let M and Bi be R-MODULE for all i in I
Show that $M \bigotimes_R (\Pi_{i\in I} B_i) \ncong \Pi_{i \in I} (M \bigotimes B_i)$
Take $R=\mathbb{Z}$, $M=\mathbb{Q}$ and $B_n =\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{P^n \mathbb{Z}}$
, n > 0

Comment: Nice exercise! Where does it come from? I can see one side is zero, and the other isn't.